# Programmatical register a Postgres Server with pgAdmin using Delphi

Tags: delphi, postgresql, pgadmin

Im working on an application using Postgres 9 and Delphi 7 as the front end,
For setting up the database connection to the application we have to do the following steps

1.Register a server in postgres 
(i cannot post an image because im new user)

```
   Name:=Localhost
   Host:=Localhost
   Port:=5432
   SSL:=
   MaintenanceDB:=myDB
   Username:=Admin
   password:=******
   .
   .
   Service:=Localhost
```

2.Create the database and the tables.

Can any one tell me if the step 1.
can be done programatically?
Like for example
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe"  -h localhost -p 5432 -d myDB -U Admin Service=Localhost  "  ?

as of now its done manually by the user.

thanks in advance:)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*register* a server"? Do you want to install Postgres and then create a windows service for it?

Comment: no,
Postgres is already installed and the service also is created,

my question is 
u must have seen on the top left corner of Postgres, there is an icon the says
'ADD connection to the server'
it looks like a plug...

so i want to know  if it possible to programttically to add a server.

Comment: There is no such thing as "*the top left corner of Postgres*". What exactly do you mean with that?

Comment: My guess is that the OP looks at pgAdmin3.

Comment: oh my bad
i meant top left corner of pgAdmin III
there is an icon on the Toolbar, that is used to create connections to the server 
'Add connections to the server'

i want to know how to add connections to the server programattically :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registered servers in pgAdmin are stored in the Windows registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III\Servers`

The number of registered servers is stored in the `Count` attribute.

Then each server gets its own entry according to the number. So the first one is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III\Servers\1`, the second one in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III\Servers\2` and so on.

Have a look into your registry and create an approriate entry from within your Delphi application.

Comment: Hey
Thank You:) :) :)
i found it

Thank u very much