# How to progamatically register a PostgreSql server using Java?

Tags: postgresql, registry

I am in the process of automating a PostgreSql installation.  I'm stuck on how to "register" a "server" (this is required for the process I'm trying to automate).

By "register a server" I mean replicate the steps performed by pgAdmin when Register->Server... is selected as shown below.

There is an indication that this is a setting in the Windows registry, but how do I create this entry from Java?
([Programmatical register a Postgres Server with pgAdmin using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163548/programmatical-register-a-postgres-server-with-pgadmin-using-delphi))

This is what I'm trying to automate from Java:
[image]
[image]